# How do I access a git branch with a ':' in the name?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-fetch

In recent months I have two PRs come at me with the branch names being 'foo:bar'. Whenever I do a `git fetch --all`, that branch is nowhere to be found. How can I get this branch to be on my local machine?

Comment: By the way you do not need to say `--all`. That means all _remotes_, not all _branches_. Fetching always fetches all branches unless you say not to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is an [illegal branch name](https://wincent.com/wiki/Legal_Git_branch_names). You should look on github (or wherever these pull requests occurred) to see what happened here.

Note, however, that if you are managing pull requests correctly, it might be normal not to be able to find that branch because, if you're like me, you always delete that branch right after the merge anyway.

Comment: Ahh I see. Looks like the branch was created with a fork so user error but have seen this on non forks too. TY!